# Dojo/HTML equivalent for list box control

Tags: widget, dojo

We are porting our MFC based client to Dojo. Is there any widget similar to listbox control. At present I am using DataGrid, but that seems heavy and overkill for our purposes. Alternatively what is best widget to replace listbox.

Update: I have already looked at dijit.form.multiselect, and I dont think that meets my requirement. MFC Listbox typically looks like this. I dont see (or rather dont know) how to replicate this with multiselect. It is possible that [DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html) is best fit for the control.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use dojo 1.7, take a look at the new [DGrid](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/10/26/introducing-the-next-grid-dgrid/#more-2893).

For an example looking like yours, go to the [tests page](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test) and pickup the [Selector.html](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Selector.html) example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options depending on which part of the ListBox you want to create:

- `dijit.Dialog` to create a basic dialog box.
- `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` to create a drop-down with your options (single select only).
- You could also use radio buttons or checkboxes for your options depending on whether multiple selections are allowed.